# Sql Query for Multiple Tables

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL AND operator not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638325/sql-and-operator-not-working-properly)

I have following two tables

LandParcels Table

```
Blockid ParcelNo storPri
 ======= ======== ======= 
52000105   3      State 
52000105   4      Private 
52000105   5      State
52000401   12     State
52001002   23     State
```

Actions Table

```
Blockid ParcelNo ActionTaken
 ======= ======== ===========
52000105   3      Received 
52000105   3      Send to Computer 
52000105   4      Received 
52000105   5      Received
52000401   12     Received  
52001002   23     Received
```

I want to filter selected blockid (eg: 52000105) and records not "Sent to Computer"

acc. to two tables

eg. I want to filter the records from landparcels where blockid 52000105 and not sent to Computer ("Received" only)

I want the result like this (Selected Block is 52000105)

```
Blockid ParcelNo ActionTaken
 ======= ======== ===========
52000105   4      Received 
52000105   5      Received
```

Comment: Why is ParcelNo 3 not in your sample output?

Comment: Possible duplicate (same query, data, table, OP) of [SQL AND operator not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638325/sql-and-operator-not-working-properly)

Comment: Please stop asking the same questions over and over: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638325/sql-and-operator-not-working-properly

Comment: @gbn: I'm out of close votes.

Answer (score 0):

> select * from LandParcels inner join
>   Actions on LandParcels.Blockid=
>   Actions.Blockid Where Actions.Blockid
>   = 52000105 and ActionTaken='Recieced'

Comment: I want received and not equal to "Send to Computer"

Comment: Did you read comments? 3rd question from same person. Don't encourage them please...

Comment: Ok thanks I want real querry. that is why i send correct info. I received some replies. But cannot get correct result.